# Prolog finding the largest integer in a list from the tail

Tags: list, prolog, tail-recursion, failure-slice

I need to find the largest integer in a list from the head of a list and alternatively from the tail. I have already written a program that can find the largest from the head now I need some help to do it from the tail.

Here is what I have so far:

```
largest([X],X).
largest([X|Xs],X) :- largest(Xs,Y), X>=Y.
largest([X|Xs],N) :- largest(Xs,N), N>X.
```

Keep in mind that this finds the largest integer from the head, and I need it to work from the tail. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This code, in fact, works from the tail. To work from the head, you need a tail-recursive version with an accumulator.

Comment: Shows how much I know, so what would that look like?

Answer (score 6):

Hold on for a second! Before you continue, first measure the time your predicate takes!

```
?- length(J,I), I>10, append(J,[2],L),maplist(=(1),J),  time(largest(L,N)).
% 12,282 inferences, 0.006 CPU in 0.006 seconds (99% CPU, 1977389 Lips)
J = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|...],
I = 11,
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|...],
N = 2 ;
% 4 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (84% CPU, 98697 Lips)
% 24,570 inferences, 0.011 CPU in 0.011 seconds (99% CPU, 2191568 Lips)
J = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|...],
I = 12,
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|...],
N = 2 ;
% 4 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (84% CPU, 98556 Lips)
% 49,146 inferences, 0.021 CPU in 0.021 seconds (100% CPU, 2365986 Lips)
J = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|...],
I = 13,
L = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1|...],
N = 2 ...
```

The number of inferences clearly doubles each time the length increases by one! That's the way how Prolog gets its bad reputation for being extremely inefficient, nixing all progress in processor speed.

So what is happening in your program? There is no need to go into details, but lets consider a small fragment ([failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)) of your program. While this resulting program is completely dysfunctional for your purpose it gives us a **lower bound** of the number of inferences in your program:

```
largest([X],X) :- false.
largest([X|Xs],X) :- largest(Xs,Y), false, X>=Y.
largest([X|Xs],N) :- largest(Xs,N), false, N>X.
```

For each element in the list, we have two equally applicable choices. So with a list of `N` elements, we have `2^N` choices!

Here is a possible rewrite:

```
largest([X],X).
largest([X|Xs],R) :-
   largest(Xs,Y),
   (  X>=Y, R = X
   ;  Y > X, R = N
   ).
```

You can do even better by using if-then-else...

```
largest([X],X).
largest([X|Xs],R) :-
   largest(Xs,Y),
   (  X>=Y -> R = X
   ;  Y > X, R = N
   ).
```

or `max/2`

```
largest([X],X).
largest([X|Xs],R) :-
   largest(Xs,Y),
   R is max(X,Y).
```

This program still requires space proportional to the length of the list. And that is what you can reduce to a constant, by using a tail-recursive version. But at least this version runs now in linear time.

And for the actual optimization you want to perform, read

[SWI-Prolog: Sum-List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391611/swi-prolog-sum-list?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The tail-recursive head-first solution looks like this:

```
largest( [X|Xs] , Max ) :- largest( Xs , X , Max ) .

largest( []     , R , R ) .
largest( [X|Xs] , T , R ) :- X >  T , largest( Xs , X , R ) .
largest( [X|Xs] , T , R ) :- X =< T , largest( Xs , T , R ) .
```

`largest/2` simply invokes `largest/3`, seeding its accumulator with the head of the list (the initial 'max' value). As `largest/3` recurses down through the list, it replaces that accumulator with a new "current" max value as it encounters them. When the list is exhausted, the accumulator has the max value for the entire list.

Your initial solution:

```
largest([X],X).
largest([X|Xs],X) :- largest(Xs,Y), X>=Y.
largest([X|Xs],N) :- largest(Xs,N), N>X.
```

runs tail-first. It recurses down to the end of the list, at which point it decides that the **last** item in the list is the initial "max" value. As it pops the stack on the way up, it compares that to the preceding value and does the needful.

The problem with your approach is two-fold:

- it runs in something like O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, as it has to repeatedly iterate over the list on each failure.
- it consumes stack space, you given a list of sufficient length, you won't be able to compute a solution due to the stack overflow you'll encounter.

On the other hand, the tail-recursive "head-first" approach runs in O(n) time: the list is iterated just once, at the end of which you have the solution. Further, due to tail-recursion optimization, the recursive call is essentially converted to iteration, meaning that no stack space is consumed outside of the initial stack frame. That means that the solution can be computed for lists of any length (provided you're willing to wait for the answer).

Comment: It does not need O(n<sup>2) as you suggest, but O(2<sup>n</sup>)

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic, tail-recursive, head-first version:

```
largest([X|Xs], O) :- largest(Xs, X, O).

largest([], O, O).
largest([X|Xs], M, O) :-
    M1 is max(X, M),
    largest(Xs, M1, O).
```