# The derivation tree of finding the maximum of a given number list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a problem in the derivation tree of finding the maximum of a given number list. How variables are assigned.?

Following are the rules in Prolog

```
max([X],X). %If one element list, the element is the maximum

max([X|L],X) :- max(L,M), X > M. %If head is greater than the maximum of tail the head is the maximum.

max([X|L],M) :- max(L,M), X =< M. %If head is less than or equal the maximum of tail, then maximum of tail is the maximum.
```

So I want to know the steps for how Prolog answer the following query.

```
?- max([10,20,30], M).
```

Please give me an idea, how recursive calls work and variables are assigned.

Thank you...

Comment: Just query `?- trace.` and then do your query. Any answer you get here will be just a more elaborate version of what the trace looks like.

Comment: In Prolog, variables are not *assigned*, but *instantiated*. It's a fundamental difference wrt procedural languages

Comment: @ CapelliC, Can you give me a basic steps about  the search tree of max([10,20,30] M). As I'm new to Prolog, my knowledge on this is very very limited.  and any disadvantages of the relations I used here?, Thanks...

Comment: @Boris give you a very good hint. Sorry but you need to take your time to follow the gory details... or try to follow by hand the execution. That's all...

Comment: The disavantage is that its complexity is quadratic. Clauses 2,3 should be merged, so the recursive call occurs only once. You should choose about the discrimination test. Personally, I would use `max([X|L],M) :- max(L,T), (X>T -> M=X;M=T).`

Comment: Actually, if you have numbers, the predicate could be something like: `max([X|Xs], Max) :- max_1(Xs, X, Max). max_1([], Max, Max). max_1([X|Xs], Max0, Max) :- Max1 is max(X, Max0), max_1(Xs, Max1, Max).` This is the exact definition in the [SWI-Prolog library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/usr/lib/swi-prolog/library/lists.pl?show=src#max_list/2). You can also take a look at `max_member/2` defined in the same library. The code you provide is correct, but rather "textbook" than "production". It is annoying that there is a difference, of course.

Comment: @CapelliC If you have a list of numbers (or arithmetic expressions of course) you can even avoid the if-then-else by using the `max()` arithmetic function. I did once try to time it and it turned out that if you have only normal numbers (no arithmetic expressions, no rationals) then `max_member/2` is faster than `max_list/2` and still correct.

Comment: @CapelliC Thank you very much for the suggestion of optimizing the recursion. So my rules were, maxlist([X],X). maxlist([X|L],M) :- maxlist(L,T), (X>T -> M=X;M=T). @ Boris your idea on "trace" helped me a lot; thank you very much for your information.

Comment: @CapelliC: The overhead is **exponential** in the length of the list. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19941560/772868) for more.