# How to does this Prolog example work?

Tags: prolog

The question Reads, "Write a Prolog program that finds the maximum of a list of numbers."

I have used the power of the internet to help find a solution that works but, I want to have an understanding of the program itself.

```
max_num([X],X).
max_num([X|Y],X):- max_num(Y,Z), X >= Z.
max_num([X|Y],A):- max_num(Y,A), A > X.
```

Line1:

```
max_num([X],X).
```

I understand that Line1 is defining the basic template of the question. The [X] defines the list and the other X represents the maximum value within that list.

Line2:

```
max_num([X|Y],X):- max_num(Y,Z), X >= Z.
```

This is where I lose track of things. I understand the first part, "max_num([X|Y],X)" and that it split the list into two parts, "A first half" and the "Second half" separated by the vertical line. and the X is just the Max Number? I am unsure at this point.

Line3: Well its just not even worth trying to comprehend now. Please comment below to help me understand the current logic of this program.

Best Regards.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19941560/772868) for an explanation  of some deep problems of this  program.

Answer (score 2):

If you are somewhat familiar with first order logic you might find it helpful to replace `:-` with logical implacation and `,` with conjunction. Then the second line of the program looks like:

`max_num([X|Y],X)` ← `max_num(Y,Z)` ∧ `X >= Z`

Note that the implication arrow goes to the left, towards the head of the rule. You can flip that around to see the implication arrow point in a more familiar direction:

`max_num(Y,Z)` ∧ `X >= Z` → `max_num([X|Y],X)`

The line reads: **If** (`Z` is the maximum of list `Y` **and** `X >= Z`) **then** `X` is the maximum of the list that has `X` as first element (head) and `Y` as the rest of the list (tail).

The same goes for the third line:

`max_num([X|Y],A)` ← `max_num(Y,A)` ∧ `A > X`

**If** (`A` is the maximum of list `Y` **and** `A > X`) **then** `A` is the maximum of the list that has `X` as head and `Y` as tail.

I am not sure what you mean by template regarding the first rule. The first line of this program is a *fact*. This is a way to say in prolog: This is always true. You could alternatively write it:

```
max_num([X],X) :- true.
```

Declaratively it says: The maximum number in a list with exactly one element `X` is that very element.

Procedurally you need this fact in order to let the program terminate (at least for lists with fixed lengths). Just think about it:

if the first argument is:

- `[X]`: The first rule matches and succeeds. The second and third rules also match because `[X] = [X|[]]` but fail in their recursive goal because max_num/2 has no rule where the empty list matches the first argument.
- `[X|Y]` with `Y` not being `[]`: The first rule does not match. But the other two do and they will recurse because `Y` is not the empty list and thus will match the first argument of max_num/2.

Answer (score 1):

The `:-` operator is used to define a *predicate clause* or *rule* in terms of other queries. You have a *predicate*, `max_num/2` (which has two arguments) that consists of three *predicate clauses* or *rules*, the first of which is a very simple rule: `max_num([X], X).` which you already noted means:

> `X` is the maximum number in the list `[X]`.

Generally, you can read `:-` as "if" for a rule:

```
max_num([X|Y],X) :- max_num(Y,Z), X >= Z.
```

Would be read:

> `X` is the maximum number of list `[X|Y]` (list with head `X`
>   and tail `Y`) **if** `Z` is the maximum
>   number of the tail `Y` **and** `X >= Z` (`X`, the head, is greater than or equal to `Z`).

Note that the "vertical line" you're referring to separates the *head* and *tail* of a list. If you do a basic Prolog tutorial or read some introductory Prolog material, this would be explained. The *head* is the first element, and the *tail* is a list that constitutes the remainder of the list. Thus, the list `[H|T]` has first element `H` and the rest of the list is list `T`.

If you understand this, then reading line 3 should be simple.